# Open LWC as a full page without salesforce header

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-web-components

I have a button on Lightning Record page. On click i am redirecting to a LWC. Is there anyway where i can redirect or open the LWC in a full screen page. As of now it is opening with salesforce main header.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lightning application and open it in Lightning without the standard header.

An **app** is a special top-level component whose markup is in a .app resource.

Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_overview.htm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this is not possible. The header is static content of the general LEX.
While you maybe could do it via css i would not recommend it because it can break at any time when salesforce changes structure / their own css.

Potentially you could also serve it via a Visualforce page and adress it this one instead which can be displayed on an own full page - but not sure if lightning out is worth the price.

i would just keep it as is to be honest